# What to call it or someone who easily laughs about something which isn't funny?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, pejorative-language

This kind of person always or easily laughs, not because something is so funny, but because that person is easily e.g. nervous, agitated, has a short attention span and hasn't really got a sense of humour.

I don't mean having the giggles.

It might be (maybe not always) this person is generally quite pretentious anyway (in case that would affect the answer), that his laughing is more like putting up a show rather than finding something truly funny.

Comment: People engage in social laughter for various reasons that have little to do with humor. I doubt there is a single word or phrase that covers all instances of this kind of behavior.

Comment: GMB - obviously I am not referring to just a laugh or social laughter. I wouldn't ask this question if it was just that...

Comment: *Nervously cheerful?* @ user76935 - you obviously *are* referring to a type of "social laughter", since you specifically say ***his laughing is more like putting up a show***.

Comment: FumbleFingers - not quite.

Comment: Do you mean that he's laughing because he doesn't know but thinks he ought to laugh? It sounds like *socially inept* might cover what you describe -- it's broad enough to cover a lot of things.

Comment: You might want to reword "bit retarded" though, if it's relevant;  or remove it altogether if it's not critical to the question.

Comment: I don't know how to reword "bit retarded". I used it because I wanted to illustrate an inconsiderate, not so intelligent person who just "easily laughs" without getting a joke or having a sense of humour.

Answer (score 3):

One of the meanings of **[risible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/risible)** is "having the ability, disposition, or readiness to laugh."

Comment: That's too general. There is more detail to it than just a laugh...

Answer (score 2):

"Easily amused" for the first description. For the last description, "[phony](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phony?s=t)" came to mind but it's not really restricted to laughing. "Someone who fake laughs`*` constantly" is more accurate but then it's no longer a pithy description that you want.

`*`note that the "s" is on "laugh" and not "fake" as fake laugh could be used as a single verb (as seen in this Time [article](http://time.com/88627/people-can-tell-when-youre-fake-laughing/))

Also, if you meant "putting up a show" as "trying to appear outgoing in an annoying way"--and not as "sucking up to another person by laughing at their jokes" that "phony" describes--"[loud](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loud)" would be my single word for that, specifically with the Merriam-Webster definition of "noisy in a way that bothers other people".

"[Overzealous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overzealous) laugher" is the best I could come up with to combine the two descriptions (and still keep it short) since it describes someone who laughs a lot in an unnatural, and perhaps vaguely insincere, way.

---

**Edit**: The "bit retarded" comment provides some context on what you're trying to say, specifically on the negative connotation that you would describe that person, almost to the point of mocking. In that case, "easily amused" might not be as negative as you'd like to, and the other definitions might not match precisely your intention. Perhaps you can use "lame/mindless/miscalibrated sense of humor" depending on how casual or negative you want to sound. How about someone with a "mindless laugh"?

Comment: Good calls. Maybe not necessary here, but generally when you put in a word that seems to fit a definition, having a link to its definition is useful (say on dictionary.com or merriam-webster.com).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've edited by answer, though for some reason I could not find the definition of "easily amused" by a quick Google search so I left it.

Comment: Those sound as considerate and could be useful suggestions.